# How to add library paths in Qt Creator like LIBPATH in Visual Studio?

Tags: qt, environment-variables, qt-creator

**Question**

a) How do we add library paths where the project should look for depended libraries in Qt Creator?

b) How are the settings in project >> Run >> Build Environment related to similar in .pro file? Does the environment variable listed there applies to .pro file as well (well they don't) so what are they exactly?

**Context/Details:**

Visual Studio has a various environment variables for [folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx) where a project looks for include files, library files or executable files etc. This is rather confusing in Qt Creator and I havne't seen good documentation on it.

The only thing which is obvious is `INCLUDEPATH`variable which points to the directories where to look for the include files (.h)

However how do I set the library paths, the path where it should look for dependent libraries/dlls etc? I can specify the exact library with `LIBS` variable in .pro file, there don't seem to equivalent of LIBPATH variable where it should look for other libraries if not found in current folder.

I have worked around this be adding library path the following way basically using LIBS variable but dropping the library file name and that seems to work and add the path but I don't see this documented anywhere.

```
LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/Xerces/bin/"
```

But what makes things more interesting is the settings in Projects >> select 'Run' from current configuration and expand the `Run Environment` settings.

'[image: Run Environment]'

Here there is LIB variable and LIBPATH variable but there are clearly not .pro environment available. It also says [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html#build-environment) that these settings are local to user and saved in `.pro.user` file which perhaps suggest it's a different way to set but it doesn't say how to set them in .pro file but it does suggest to set them there if want to apply for all users!

Likewise there are [DEPENDPATH](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#dependpath) AND VPATH and it is not really clearly what they are used for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough Rep to add comments to your question, So am adding my comment in form of answer. I am pretty new to Qt and have been developing Qt GUI application on Linux.

I set this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable with the path to my Qt libraries. Am not sure how much it will be helpful to you since you are using visual studio on windows.

Comment: I am not using visual studio, I only mentioned that for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

in Projects property go to Build Environment and add a variable with the libs path, example NAME_LIBPATH. So in the .pro file add the following:

```
# your lib configuration
LIBS += -L$$(NAME_LIBPATH) \
    -llibname
```